# TYPO3 How to handle routes for custom extensions

Tags: routes, typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-10.x

Lat's say that I've got hypothetical **ZOO** extension, which has just **Animal** model, and **Showroom** plugin for displaying simple `list` and `show` actions. Very basic case so far.

**Animal** model contains just two fields `name` which is supposed to be URI part and `color`... just color.

SQL for it is just

```sql
CREATE TABLE tx_zoo_domain_model_animal (
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    color varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
);
```

For linking to the single view (`show` action) we can use simple URI w/out route enhancer:

```
/zoo?tx_zoo_showroom[action]=show&tx_zoo_showroom[animal]=123&tx_zoo_showroom[controller]=Animal&cHash=17c7b0009b50eaf0222fe66d9f
```

Next, to add routing for our extension we'd like to add such enhancer within `typo3conf/sites/yoursite/config.yaml`

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  Zoo:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 107  # it's always good idea to limit enhancers only to pages containing plugin
    extension: Zoo
    plugin: Showroom
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'Animal::list'
      - routePath: '/{animal-name}'
        _controller: 'Animal::show'
        _arguments:
          animal-name: animal
    aspects:
      animal-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_zoo_domain_model_animal
        routeFieldName: name
```

which results with a link like `http://domain.tld/zoo/Elephant`

so far, so good, anyway we meet several problems here:

- URI isn't lowercase
- it doesn't replace spaces so if we have an animal with *Ultra Weird Fish* name the URI will be `http://domain.tld/zoo/Ultra%20Weird%20Fish` instead of `http://domain.tld/zoo/ultra-weird-fish`
- it doesn't care about uniqueness, so when we'll add several animals i.e. with Fish name, but different color it will create the same URI for all of them: `http://domain.tld/zoo/Ultra%20Weird%20Fish`

How to properly handle this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

In this case, we should use additional field in our model/table, for an example `slug` like in `pages` TCA. The first thing to do is adding it to our SQL in `typo3conf/ext/zoo/ext_tables.sql`

```sql
CREATE TABLE tx_zoo_domain_model_animal (
    name varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    color varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
    slug varchar(2048), -- quite large value, but your name/slug may be loooong
);
```

then we need to add config for the new field if TCA of our table `typo3conf/ext/zoo/Configuration/TCA/tx_zoo_domain_model_animal.php`

```php
<?php
return [
    'ctrl' => [...],
    'interface' => [
        // add slug to showRecordFieldList
        'showRecordFieldList' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, name, slug, color',
    ],
    'types' => [
        // add slugto showitem
        '1' => ['showitem' => 'sys_language_uid, l10n_parent, l10n_diffsource, hidden, name, slug, color, --div--;LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:tabs.access, starttime, endtime'],
    ],
    'columns' => [
        'sys_language_uid' => [...],
        'l10n_parent' => [...],
        'l10n_diffsource' => [...],
        't3ver_label' => [...],
        'hidden' => [...],
        'starttime' => [...],
        'endtime' => [...],

        'name' => [...],
        'color' => [...],
        // add config for slug
        'slug' => [
            'exclude' => true,
            'label' => 'Slug',
            'displayCond' => 'VERSION:IS:false',
            'config' => [
                'type' => 'slug',
                'size' => 50,
                'generatorOptions' => [
                    'fields' => ['name'],
                    'replacements' => [
                        '/' => '-'
                    ],
                ],
                'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
                'eval' => 'uniqueInSite', // optionaly 'unique' can be used to make sure it's unique within whole TYPO3 instance.
                'default' => ''
            ]
        ],

    ],
];
```

and finally edit our route enhancer to use `slug` instead of the `name` within `typo3conf/sites/yoursite/config.yaml`:

```yaml
routeEnhancers:
  Zoo:
    type: Extbase
    limitToPages:
      - 107  # it's always good idea to limit enhancers only to pages containing plugin
    extension: Zoo
    plugin: Showroom
    routes:
      - routePath: '/'
        _controller: 'Animal::list'
      - routePath: '/{animal-name}'
        _controller: 'Animal::show'
        _arguments:
          animal-name: animal
    aspects:
      animal-name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_zoo_domain_model_animal
        routeFieldName: slug
```

Thanks to this approach `slug` field will be handled properly during form editing in backend:

[image: slug type in TCA]

**ProTip** As usual, after each change in your code, especially in  `config.yaml` ***DO NOT FORGET*** to clear all your caches million times :D

**In addition to questions in comments**

Using number suffix for non-unique URI's is standard behaviour for routing (or URL rewriting in general) in TYPO3 for really long time. Actually using added `slug` field allows you to enter custom slug for each item, instead of having `elephant-1` and `elephant-2`.

Optionally you can also modify the TCA for the slug field to combine more fields from DB like without need for manual slug editing:

```php
'slug' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'Slug',
    'displayCond' => 'VERSION:IS:false',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'slug',
        'size' => 50,
        'generatorOptions' => [
            'fields' => ['name', 'color'], // combine more fields
            'fieldSeparator' => '/', // or '-' if you want slug like 'elephant-cyan' instead of `elephant/cyan`
            'replacements' => [
                '/' => '-'
            ],
        ],
        'fallbackCharacter' => '-',
        'eval' => 'uniqueInSite', // optional 'unique' can be used
        'default' => ''
    ]
],
```

Which automatically create slugs basing on the value of `color` field, like:

- http://domain.tld/zoo/elephant/pink-with-little-mint-note
- http://domain.tld/zoo/elephant/yellow
- http://domain.tld/zoo/elephant/blue

BE preview:

[image: combined columns for slug]

**appearance config in the TCA**

Since TYPO3 ver.: `10.x` it's possible to add a custom prefix to the slug field using class  [presented in documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html#appearance) it will just add the prefix similar to this one you can see at translated pages/records.

[image: Slug's prefix]

Actually it inherits two arguments, `$parameters` and `$reference` to `TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Form\FormDataProvider\TcaSlug` so it can be used i.e. for adding language part of the route, however, it's already done, so I don't find at the moment to much other usages.

Comment: Note: this is the self-answering question, I'll accept it after some time unless someone comes up with a better solution. Feel free to share your solutions above then I'll accept and/or bounty the best of suggested.

Comment: so assumed there exists a red and a green elephant in the database-table (ok, with elephants it's not a real world example :D ) how the slugs are supposed being created automatically? I'd desire something better than just `elephant`, `elephant-1`, `elephant-2`

Comment: No, but I have yellow and pink with mint :D Check my edit for possibilities. Without any changes to original solution you can still manually change slug for each item

Comment: you've an exquisite choice of colors :D  After your edit I can add my green elephant with red dots too ;-) So till now you never use any extra class for slug-handling - while on the one hand it's less complicated and easier on the other hand an example for that option is missing.

Comment: Feel free to add one ;)

Comment: BTW, Custom class handling is mentioned in the documentation: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/Slug.html

Comment: Yes, the example there with `return 'custom base url';`  is a bit strange though and never explains the need or options for it.