# How do I get TYPO3 custom extension route to work?

Tags: typo3, typo3-11.x

Perhaps am missing something. I've searched and found answers such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982933/typo3-how-to-handle-routes-for-custom-extensions). For me, the whole thing doesn't work.

So my pages load via TypoScript (as one might expect):

```
# PAGE
# **********************
page=PAGE
page{
    typeNum=0
    shortcutIcon=favicon.ico

    10=USER
    10{
        userFunc=TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        extensionName=Shop
        pluginName=Main
    }
}
```

I have a couple of pages (1 and 2) and they all work fine. Page 1 is root page.

Then I have routes that look like this:

```
routeEnhancers:
    Account:
        type: Extbase
        limitToPages:
            - 1
        extension: Shop
        plugin: Account
        routes:
            -   routePath: /a
                _controller: 'Account::accountLogin'

            -   routePath: /a/r
                _controller: 'Account::accountRegistration'
```

My plugin registration in ext_localconf.php looks like this:

```
/**
 * Plugins
 */
(static function(){
    ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin('shop', 'Page', [PageController::class=>'main']);
    ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin('shop', 'Account', [AccountController::class=>'accountLogin,accountRegistration']);
})();
```

When I try to access the root page `https://127.0.0.1/` it works fine. When I access a subpage (page 2) of page 1, everything works fine as well. But when I try to access `https://127.0.0.1/a`, the request never hits the `accountLogin` action of the `AccountController`. Neither does `https://127.0.0.1/a/r`. So I checked under the hood and found that The `PageResolver` middleware does indeed single out the correct `routePath` from the list of available paths. The controller and action of the route is then carried in a `PageArguments` object. All looks good but it never gets to the `accountLogin` action. It's totally ignored in the process.

Previously with earlier versions it worked fine.

What could I be doing wrong? or did some change take place with the new version?

Using version 11.5.8

Comment: maybe something very simple. Did you add the plugins to the the corresponding subpages?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Thanks. Yes, they're added.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the TypoScript carrying the plugin for the `AccountController` was not loaded.